# FabricJS image object clipTo shape object issue

Tags: image, object, fabricjs, shapes

Why this clipTo method doesn't work on the latest fabricjs version, which you could resize the object container and the image inside it. Also you able to move the container object and image object.

```
   var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                width: instanceWidth,
                height: instanceHeight,
                top: (canvas.getHeight() / 2 - instanceHeight / 2),
                left: (canvas.getWidth() / 2 - instanceWidth / 2),
                originX: 'left',
                originY: 'top'
            });
            canvas.add(imgInstance);
            imgInstance.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                /* image clipping method doesn't work on latest fabricjs version*/
                ctx.save();
                ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

                clippingRect.render(ctx);

                ctx.restore();
            };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efmbrm4v/2/

Or is their another approach shape object inside is the image object.

Comment: Yep, I want to have like that functionality on the latest fabricjs version.

Comment: and also why that code doesn't work on the latest version @ℊααnd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some caching issue with the latest version of FabricJS. To get around that, you need to set **`objectCaching`** property to `false` for the rectangle object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
   imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

var clippingRect = new fabric.Rect({
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: 'transparent',
   opacity: 1,
   objectCaching: false //<-- set this
});
canvas.add(clippingRect);

function handleImage(e) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(event) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {

         var instanceWidth, instanceHeight;

         instanceWidth = img.width;
         instanceHeight = img.height;

         var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
            width: instanceWidth,
            height: instanceHeight,
            top: (canvas.getHeight() / 2 - instanceHeight / 2),
            left: (canvas.getWidth() / 2 - instanceWidth / 2),
            originX: 'left',
            originY: 'top'
         });
         canvas.add(imgInstance);
         imgInstance.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

            clippingRect.render(ctx);

            ctx.restore();
         };
         canvas.renderAll();
      };
      img.src = event.target.result;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<br />
<label>Choose a File:</label>
<br/>
<br />
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow, I already try that objectcache but I put it on the wrong object.

Comment: when I try to save the canvas to JSON then load it again, It gives me an error clippingRect.render(ctx); is undefined. Do you any idea?

Comment: um.. there seems to be an issue with that, can't find the solution atm.

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ didn't you find any soloution yet?

Comment: why this solution doesn't work in android chrome browser?