# add an image within an existing shape in FabricJs

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Salam;
I want to add new image inside an existing shape in FabricJs.
I checked clipTo Function but I realized that it's working for clipping in an special shape, How can I hide Image details below the existing shape?

in another word , I have a shape and I want to upload a shape inside it!?
sorry for being amateur! :)

Comment: what made you stop from using clipTo function? You can upload an image into existing shape using the same function.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb can you give me an example how can I use clipTo to clip image inside shape?

Comment: This is already discussed in a thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743369/fabricjs-image-object-clipto-shape-object-issue